# image hover effect all at the same time

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an all css and bootstrap hover effect, the `overlay` tags are all encased in a div class but all of them hover at the same time. all three have separate bootstrap grids and the effect even extends to the empty space in between the photos. any help would be appreciated thank you.

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 text-align-center">
        <h2 class="bold_font">BROWSE OUR CARDS</h2><br>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
        <a href="cards/list.php?tn=beauty">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="img/_stock_mwc_beauty.jpg">
          <div class="overlay">
            <div class="overlay-content">
              <img src="img/icon-beauty-white.png" class="img-responsive center-block">
              <div class="spacer overlay-text">BEAUTY</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
        <a href="cards/list.php?tn=health">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="img/_stock_mwc_health.jpg">
          <div class="overlay">
            <div class="overlay-content">
              <img src="img/icon-health-white.png" class="img-responsive center-block">
              <div class="spacer overlay-text">HEALTH</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
        <a href="cards/list.php?tn=wellness">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="img/_stock_mwc_wellness.jpg">
          <div class="overlay">
            <div class="overlay-content">
              <img src="img/icon-wellness-white.png" class="img-responsive center-block">
              <div class="spacer overlay-text">WELLNESS</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  background-color: #f08300;
}

.container:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}

.overlay-content {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.spacer {
    margin: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
}
```

here is my js fiddle for more info, i just added random placeholder images: http://jsfiddle.net/cnkgqhdw/1/

Comment: One starting point on where you have a crucial error: you add every overlay as soon as you hover over the container, so `.container:hover .overlay` should be changed to something like `.col-md-4:hover .overlay` Ideally you add a class to your cards and add the hover effect there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do the `hover` on the `container`, do it on the columns! Just change `.container:hover` to `.col-md-4:hover`.

To keep the space correct, you can use bootstrap own [spacing system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/). In your case, you can put a default margin around by adding the class `mx-3` to the `overlay` element.

```css
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  background-color: #f3a64c;
}

.col-md-4:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}

.overlay-content {
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.exact-center {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.spacer {
  margin: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-align-center">
      <h2 class="bold_font">BROWSE OUR CARDS</h2><br>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="img/_stock_mwc_beauty.jpg">
      <div class="overlay mx-3">
        <div class="overlay-content">
          <img src="img/icon-beauty-white.png" class="img-responsive center-block">
          <div class="spacer overlay-text">BEAUTY</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="img/_stock_mwc_health.jpg">
      <div class="overlay mx-3">
        <div class="overlay-content">
          <img src="img/icon-health-white.png" class="img-responsive center-block">
          <div class="spacer overlay-text">HEALTH</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="img/_stock_mwc_wellness.jpg">
      <div class="overlay mx-3">
        <div class="overlay-content px-3">
          <img src="img/icon-wellness-white.png" class="img-responsive center-block">
          <div class="spacer overlay-text">WELLNESS</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have it setup to `:hover` on the `.container` element, which is the entire row.  Need to add a class to your card and do `.card:hover`

Answer (score 0):

You are hovering on the whole container. So that's why everything gets the hover state.

You should add a class to the

```
<a class="item" href="">
```

and hover that:

```
.item:hover {
  //styling here
}
```